# Interface that extracts a boolean or String

Tags: java, software-design

So I have a data class that is somewhat laid out as:

```
class MyData {
  String str1,str2,str3;
  Boolean bool1,bool2;
}
```

The attributes are to be populated based upon a String input, something like:

```
public void populate(String s) {
  if(s.contains("somevalue") myData.setStr1("xxx");
  if(s.constains("something else") myData.setBool1(true);
  else myData.setBool1(false);
}
```

This is, of course, a pretty horrible way to do things as `s.contains` are actually some pretty hairy conditions, so instead I defined an interface:

```
public interface DataFinderInterface {
    public String findStringData(final String input);
    public Boolean findBooleanData(final String input);
}
```

Therefore the populate method could be rewritten as:

```
public void populate(String s) {
  myData.setStr1(str1Finder.findStringData(s));
  myData.setBool1(bool1Finder.findBooleanData(s);
}
```

The implementations of this interface either define a findStringData or a findBooleanData, which is quite unsatisfying.  The populate method needs to know if we are expecting to use the findStringData method or the findBooleanData method.

Is there a better way to do this?  Am I being overly picky, because the populate method needs to know what instance of DataFinderInterface to assign to what field anyway?

Comment: I don't know if it's only me, but your question is not really clear to me. This really seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/196975). May be you should first explain your problem statement. What exactly you are trying to do, and then what you currently have.

Comment: Does populate also need to be able to set `str2`, `str3` and `bool2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `findData` method returning a `String` should be sufficient: the code that processes `Booleans` can put a call to [`Boolean.getBoolean()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String%29) on top of it:

```
public interface DataFinderInterface {
    public String findData(final String input);
}
...
myData.setBool1(Boolean.getBoolean(bool1Finder.findData(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the above (or ONE of the problems) is that you are always calling `setStr1` AND `setBool1` and I assume you will be calling all of the others as well.

If you MUST use something like the above pattern you might want to consider having `MyData` hold `AtomicRefernce<String>` and `AtomicReference<Boolean>`. Then have `getSettableString` and `getSettableBoolean` methods that returns the appropriate reference or null if no match.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only the interface method signature you are worried about this could be solved using generics. However it does seem a little weird to initialize an object from a string that way. Perhaps if you add more details about what problem you are trying to solve, there might be a better solution.

```
public interface DataFinder<T> {
    public T findData(final String input);
}

DataFinder<String> str1Finder = new ... // a class implementing DataFinder<String>
DataFinder<Boolean> bool1Finder = new ... // a class implementing DataFinder<Boolean>

public void populate(String s) {
  myData.setStr1(str1Finder.findData(s));
  myData.setBool1(bool1Finder.findData(s);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider using regular expressions to extract the data you need from the input string. I would leave the MyData class as a simple data container and build a separate class for populating it - for example, a MyDataBuilder. This class could use string matching in order to extract the fields and populate them on the object.